# Python3.7: Metaclassing from Tuple base class, receiving Type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create metaclass:

```
from typing import Tuple

class StructMeta(Tuple):
    pass

class Struct(metaclass=StructMeta):
    pass

print(type(Struct))
```

Execute:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
class Struct(metaclass=StructMeta):
TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 3
```

Do not understand why this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typing.Tuple` appears to be a subclass of `tuple`, which only takes one argument, an iterable.

When creating a class, Python passes 3 arguments to its metaclass: the class name, a tuple of base classes, and a dict representing the class body.

It's not really possible to use `typing.Tuple` as a metaclass.